# How to get mail when firebase function got timeout or crash?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using rest api with secret key and after that key used lots of time or expiring some time later (don't know how key's expire time works) need to change secret key with new one. I want to get e-mail when key expired because users can't use my app if secret key isn't working. I don't want to check it all the time.

While key is working i'm getting json body with params but when key expired getting "not logged in" message inside body. I'm thinking to make mail sender function(can use mailgun etc...) if i get "not logged in" body but **want to learn if some way to make firebase mail me with params when function got timeout or crash**

Comment: Can  you be more specific about what do you mean by secret key? How and where did you configure it (client side and server side)? How are you using them? 
Without any further details I don't think that the best approach is using an external service for this specific matter, but to review your specific usage of the key

Comment: Secret key part isn't important for my question. That's just extra info about why am i need it. Main question is "want to learn if some way to make firebase mail me with params when function got timeout or crash" as i said at title

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in feature that I know that can do that, however you can create a function that writes all the information you want into a Cloud Firestore collection when the secret key expires and use this [Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) that triggers every time you add a new document to that collection.